# Bar-chart zoom confuses data filtering on DC chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have quite a long period of observations (tornadoes) 800-2016 (about 2000 inputs). To visualize them on one bar chart I use mouseZoomable (true) function for DC.js but it starts to mess filtering: User can't properly select interval on the chart, it slips all the time and seems as asynchronized.

Sorry I am very new to D3 and DC.js and couldn't find an answer.

Here is my code:

```js
var ndx = crossfilter(records);
var YearDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Year"]; });
var numRecordsByYear = YearDim.group();
var minYear = YearDim.bottom(1)[0]["Year"]; 
var maxYear = YearDim.top(1)[0]["Year"];
var timeChart = dc.barChart("#time-chart");   
 
timeChart
  .width(600)
  .height(140)
  .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 40, left: 40})
  .dimension(YearDim)
        .group(numRecordsByYear)
  .transitionDuration(500)
        .mouseZoomable(true)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minYear, maxYear]))
        .zoomOutRestrict([true])
  .elasticY(true)
```

Will be very gratefull for helping or suggesting another way to visualize long and irregular time interval.

Comment: Is `numRecordsByYear` based on `YearDim`? It's hard to say without looking at it. Could you [fork this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/u57bfje8/) and create a demo?

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the answer. Yes, it is. I added some lines of code in the code snippet here. Sorry I have never try fiddle or smth to create a demo. Need time to sort out.

Comment: Do you observe the same problem in [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html?interval=day)?

Comment: @Gordon No, I don't. This chart doesn't have same problem. I think that is because this example hasn't '.mouseZoomable'...

Comment: I updated dc.js version and the problem disappeared. But now when I zoom to some interval and then use brush to select some part of that interval I can't zoom out. It seems blocked. I have to use restart button. Is it normal?

Comment: That certainly sounds like a bug! Again, if you have any way of sharing a running example, that would definitely help us troubleshoot.